# Rebbe wearing new garments during shloshim

Tags: halacha, minhag, clothing, mourning-aveilus, chassidic-rebbe

I recently heard from a couple of Bnei Brak Wizniter chassidim that their rebbes (R' Yisroel and R' Mendel) wore new clothing for Pesach 5772, less than a month [after their father passed away](http://jewishvoiceny.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=717:vizhnitzer-rebbe-of-bnei-brak-passes-away-at-95&catid=127:obituaries&Itemid=333).

How could they do so when it is [standard mourning practice](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/281616/jewish/The-Twelve-Months.htm) not to wear a new garment within thirty days of a relative's passing?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is very simple. Someone else wore these new garments prior to the Rabbi wearing them. See [Nitei Gavriel Aveilus2 10:12:21](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46540&st=&pgnum=82&hilite=).

Comment: It appears to me that this would only work after finishing shloshim. However, it got me thinking: Maybe the rebbes didn't put on the new garment until after yom tov came in, thus terminating shloshim. And then they could put one something someone had worn before them.

Comment: Can you cite evidence that someone else wore the clothes?

Comment: @msh210 The fact that the Muncatcher rebbe had someone wear his clothing first makes it likely, no? Maybe I can ask one of the people close to the rebbe... I work for Bnei Brak Wiznitz' administration. :-)

Comment: @msh210: No I do not have evidence, yet I am sure that they would not wear new cloths otherwise.

Comment: on yontiff one does not show outward signs of mourning. Additionally many wear new garments on yontiff to strengthen the reason we would be saying a shehechiyanu on both nights during kiddush or during bentch licht.

Answer (score 2):

[When *Pesach* started, it cut short *sh'loshim* (the "thirty days" you speak of).](/a/64091)